# 1136 MySQL error - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table(table_name) with the condition:

```
UPDATE `table_name` 
SET `column1` = 123
WHERE `column1` = 100 
AND `column2` NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

But getting the 1136-error. 
When the condition rows matching are 0, the update is working, but when the condition matching rows are more than 1 or more the update is not working.
There is 1 trigger on the table for UPDATE.

Comment: what is the code in the trigger ?

Comment: Must be the trigger; the update statement looks fine.

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: Just check your trigger code.Where you had mention `SELECT *` or something.So count of column and values are not getting matched.So this error is occeured.

Comment: When the `WHERE` condition doesn't match any row the `UPDATE` query completes successfully because the trigger doesn't run. Post the code of the trigger.

Comment: CASE WHEN (new.column1=123 OR new.column1=456) THEN
INSERT INTO table2
VALUES (id,new.column1,new.column2,new.column3,new.column4,new.column5,new.column6,new.column7);
ELSE
BEGIN
END;
END CASE

Comment: The above is the trigger condition

Comment: There are two triggers one after insert and one after update with same condition